# Please help identify a Soviet SciFi movie from ~1950s

Tags: story-identification

The only things I remember was that it was a propaganda SciFi movie about Americans developing some sort of WMD, and fights to own it. It was infamous as really bad propaganda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, accidentally stumbled on the answer. The movie was called "Silvery dust" ("СЕРЕБРИСТАЯ ПЫЛЬ", Mosfilm, 1953), based on August Jackobson's play "Jackals".

Here's [the plot](http://www.kinoexpert.ru/index.asp?comm=4&num=5749):

> Американский ученый профессор Стил изобретает мощное оружие массового уничтожения - радиоактивную серебристо-серую пыль. Вокруг этого избретения разгорается ожесточенная борьба двух военно-промышленных трестов-гигантов, одна из которых подкупает гангстеров - и те убивают Стила, назначившего непомерно высокую цену за свое изобретение. Его старший сын Гарри придает гласности чудовищное изобретение отца, а младший сын, член фашистской партии, становится первой жертвой смертоносного действия серебристой пыли.
>
> American scientist Professor Steele invents a powerful weapon of mass destruction - a radioactive silvery-gray dust. Fierce fighting eruptes over this invention between the two military-industrial giant trusts, one of which hires gangsters - and they kill Steele who named too big of a price for his invention. His eldest son Harry gives publicity to the monstrous invention of his father, and the younger son, a member of the Fascist Party, becomes the first victim of the deadly silvery dust.

**The movie was indeed associated with a propaganda scandal.**

From the philology work by Loschilov et al, which was timed with 100 year anniversary of Zabolotsky (Лощилов, И.Е. О работе Н. Заболоцкого в кино // "Странная" поэзия и "странная" проза: Филологический сборник, посвященный 100-летию со дня рождения Н.А. Заболоцкого. Новейшие исследования русской культуры. Вып. 3. М., "Пятая страна", 2003, 124-128 - http://kniga.websib.ru/text.htm?book=28&chap=45 ):

> "Официально фильм не объявлялся идейно ошибочным. Утверждают, что американское посольство в Москве, встревоженное явным перебором глупостей (едва ли не правительство США якобы санкционирует опыты над людьми), заявило настолько решительный протест, что до скандала дело не стали доводить, а просто убрали "Серебристую пыль" из проката" (Мокроусов 2001).
>
> "Officially, the film was never declared ideologically flawed. However, people claimed that the U.S. embassy in Moscow was extremely worried about the set of absurdities ("U.S. government allegedly authorizes experiments on people"), expressed such a strong protest that the powers that be decided to avoid the scandal and simply removed "The silvery dust" from theater showings (cite: Mokrousov 2001).

Answer (score 4):

Was there a Soviet submarine called "Pioneer" in it? Then it is the movie "The Mystery of the two Oceans".  Are there any other pointers?  Was it set in space?